# s3 for GeoTIFF - mask band ignored in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, geotiff-tiff, rasterio

**Goal**: Cloud Optimised Geot4iffs (COG) that display without edge artefacts in Geoserver.

**Problem**: It doesn't display nicely: GeoServer appears to be ignoring the internal mask on the input GeoTIFF

**Question**: Why is GeoServer not picking up the internal masking of the COG?

[image: image appears to be ignoring internal masks]

**Steps Taken:**

1. Built cloud optimised GeoTIFF using the following commands.

   gdalbuildvrt doq_index.vrt *.tif

   gdal_translate -r lanczos -b 1 -b 2 -b 3 -mask mask  -of gtiff -ot /
   Byte -co "NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS" -co "SPARSE_OK=TRUE" -co "TILED=YES" /
   -co "BLOCKXSIZE=512" -co "TILED=YES" -co "BLOCKYSIZE=512"   /
   doq_index.vrt out.tif

   gdaladdo -r lanczos --config COMPRESS_OVERVIEW JPEG  --config /
   PHOTOMETRIC_OVERVIEW YCBCR -–config JPEG_QUALITY_OVERVIEW 50 /
   out.tif 2 4 8 16 32 64

   gdal_translate -r lanczos -co TILED=YES -co COMPRESS=JPEG -co /
   "NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS" -co PHOTOMETRIC=YCBCR -co JPEG_QUALITY=50 /
    -co COPY_SRC_OVERVIEWS=YES -co BLOCKXSIZE=512 -co BLOCKYSIZE=512 /
    --config GDAL_TIFF_OVR_BLOCKSIZE 512 --config GDAL_TIFF_INTERNAL_MASK /
    YES  out.tif out_512-50.tif

The resulting gdalinfo looks like this

```
    c:\temp4>gdalinfo out_512-50.tif
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: out_512-50.tif
Size is 53760, 28800
Coordinate System is:
BOUNDCRS[
    SOURCECRS[
        PROJCRS["NZGD2000 / New Zealand Transverse Mercator 2000",
            BASEGEOGCRS["NZGD2000",
                DATUM["New Zealand Geodetic Datum 2000",
                    ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
                PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                ID["EPSG",4167]],
            CONVERSION["New Zealand Transverse Mercator 2000",
                METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
                    ID["EPSG",9807]],
                PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                    ID["EPSG",8801]],
                PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",173,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                    ID["EPSG",8802]],
                PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,
                    SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
                    ID["EPSG",8805]],
                PARAMETER["False easting",1600000,
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                    ID["EPSG",8806]],
                PARAMETER["False northing",10000000,
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                    ID["EPSG",8807]]],
            CS[Cartesian,2],
                AXIS["northing (N)",north,
                    ORDER[1],
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
                AXIS["easting (E)",east,
                    ORDER[2],
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
            USAGE[
                SCOPE["unknown"],
                AREA["New Zealand - onshore"],
                BBOX[-47.33,166.37,-34.1,178.63]],
            ID["EPSG",2193]]],
    TARGETCRS[
        GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
            DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
                ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
            PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
            CS[ellipsoidal,2],
                AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
                    ORDER[1],
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
                    ORDER[2],
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
            USAGE[
                SCOPE["unknown"],
                AREA["World"],
                BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],
            ID["EPSG",4326]]],
    ABRIDGEDTRANSFORMATION["Transformation to WGS84",
        METHOD["Position Vector transformation (geog2D domain)",
            ID["EPSG",9606]],
        PARAMETER["X-axis translation",0,
            ID["EPSG",8605]],
        PARAMETER["Y-axis translation",0,
            ID["EPSG",8606]],
        PARAMETER["Z-axis translation",0,
            ID["EPSG",8607]],
        PARAMETER["X-axis rotation",0,
            ID["EPSG",8608]],
        PARAMETER["Y-axis rotation",0,
            ID["EPSG",8609]],
        PARAMETER["Z-axis rotation",0,
            ID["EPSG",8610]],
        PARAMETER["Scale difference",1,
            ID["EPSG",8611]]]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (1794400.000000000000000,5538480.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (0.125000000000000,-0.125000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=YCbCr JPEG
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
  SOURCE_COLOR_SPACE=YCbCr
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( 1794400.000, 5538480.000) (175d17'12.27"E, 40d16'53.70"S)
Lower Left  ( 1794400.000, 5534880.000) (175d17'16.21"E, 40d18'50.37"S)
Upper Right ( 1801120.000, 5538480.000) (175d21'56.62"E, 40d16'47.98"S)
Lower Right ( 1801120.000, 5534880.000) (175d22' 0.69"E, 40d18'44.65"S)
Center      ( 1797760.000, 5536680.000) (175d19'36.45"E, 40d17'49.20"S)
Band 1 Block=512x512 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  NoData Value=255
  Overviews: 26880x14400, 13440x7200, 6720x3600, 3360x1800, 1680x900, 840x450
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET
  Overviews of mask band: 26880x14400, 13440x7200, 6720x3600, 3360x1800, 1680x900, 840x450
Band 2 Block=512x512 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  NoData Value=255
  Overviews: 26880x14400, 13440x7200, 6720x3600, 3360x1800, 1680x900, 840x450
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET
  Overviews of mask band: 26880x14400, 13440x7200, 6720x3600, 3360x1800, 1680x900, 840x450
Band 3 Block=512x512 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  NoData Value=255
  Overviews: 26880x14400, 13440x7200, 6720x3600, 3360x1800, 1680x900, 840x450
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET
  Overviews of mask band: 26880x14400, 13440x7200, 6720x3600, 3360x1800, 1680x900, 840x450
```

2. Loaded image to S3
3. Configured GeoServer access to image, tested it - result:
   [image: image appears to be ignoring internal masks]
4. Tested image directly in QGIS 
   The images display as desired in QGIS using the COG from S3 e.g. 
   [image]
5. Tested image as COG from s3 in QGIS - it works.
6. Concluded it must be a GeoServer issue (note I am running GeoServer 2.14)

The GeoServer layer is setup with the following properties
[image]

The GeoServer style is using the default raster configuration.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, mask bands can only be used inside a image mosaic. You could make a image mosaic of one Tiff, and then configure mask usage (it's not on by default).

Comment: Thanks Andrea, given that the imagery in question are terabytes I am hoping to store on S3 as COGs - have you got any other suggestions that might help get me on the right track?